# BlackBerry Browser used in 9800

Tags: blackberry

could any one please let us know which Browser is used in "BB 9800" OS-6.
**"Browser Name"**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the HTTP `User-Agent` header, it is as follows (at least on my 9800, anyway):

`Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.600 Mobile Safari/534.8+`

Answer (score 0):

Its that or OperaMini 6 mainly : [BlackBerry 9800 User Agents](http://www.handsetdetection.com/properties/vendormodel/RIM/BlackBerry%209800) List.